# How do I scale my input so that outliers aren't throwing off the data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-scaling

I've scaled my inputs between -1 and 1 but outliers are still throwing my data off. i.e. 99% of the range is occupied by one outlier and the rest of the data sits between -0.001 and 0.001.

I see that one way to handle this problem is to take the logarithm of all the data before scaling it. But you can't take the logarithm of a negative value. So how should I handle outliers here? Is there some way to utilize the logarithm still?

Comment: Why do you have outliers in the data? What do they represent? Are those valid values or incorrect ones?

Comment: @Tim they are valid values. They are continuous values and each sample contains 200 of them.

Comment: If they are valid, why do you want to change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling input (and sometimes the reponse/label) is a fairly common/fundamental task and there are many different ways to achieve it. Some fairly common examples are:

- Standardization (mean variance scaling): [See Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling)
- MinMax Scaling (which I assume is the scaling method you used here) [See Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-features-to-a-range)
- Nonlinear Scaling/Transformation [See Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#non-linear-transformation)
- Normalization [See Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#normalization)

Among many others of course. I should also mention Inverse Rank Transformation which is fairly common.

**Now with regards to your question:** I recommend using [**robust scaling**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html#sklearn-preprocessing-robustscaler) unless of course you have to stick to a range, which then there are other solutions to address that.